# Dropdown option menu repeat same option

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc

This is what I implemented using spring-mvc. As I observed `resultSet` in `ChildNameAccess.java` works properly. As I put print statement here it print what I really need as  the options. But dropdown box repeats the one result in the resultset object. Could anybody trace this and tell me what's wrong with my jsp please?

controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/my_children", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public void viewMyChild(Model model) { 
    ChildNameAccess childNameDAO = new ChildNameAccess(); 

    try{
        java.util.List<Child> children = childNameDAO.getChildDataByMotherId("M-2"); 
        model.addAttribute("children",children);

        System.out.println(children);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

my_children.jsp

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
<form:form method="get" >
    <div class="div_box">
        <select>
            <option value="top" >Select child</option>
                <c:forEach items="${children}" var="children">
                    <option value="" >${children.firstName} ${children.lastName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
        </select>
            <br>

    <div align ="justify">
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='/web/mother/my_child_details'" class="btn btn-success active">View Details</button>
    </div>
        </div>
</form:form>
```

ChildNameAccess.java

```
package com.emidwife.web.models.dataAccess;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.emidwife.web.models.entities.Child;
import com.emidwife.web.models.utilities.Database;


public class ChildNameAccess {
private Database connection = new Database();
Child child = new Child();

public List<Child> getChildDataByMotherId(String motherID) throws SQLException {

    connection.openConnection();

    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
    try{
        ResultSet resultSet = connection.getData("SELECT * FROM childdetails WHERE MotherID=\'" + motherID + "\'");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
            child.setChildId(resultSet.getString("ChildID"));//database column -->ChildID
            child.setMotherId(resultSet.getString("MotherID"));
            child.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
            child.setLastName(resultSet.getString("LastName"));
            System.out.println(children);
            children.add(child);
            System.out.println(children);
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        connection.closeConnection();
    }

    return children;
}
```

}

Comment: provide your database values please

Comment: How can I? just mention here?

Comment: I would need what is the resultset you are getting when your query is executed. Also why your controller method is void? it should return the updated model object instead of working with existing model.

Comment: ChildID | MotherID | FirstName | LastName | DOB |

4 |  M­2 | HARITHA | BOTHEJU | 2013­04­04 |
5 | M­2 | SHANUKI | BOTHEJU |  2012­05­01
 this the part of the db table I access. I need print 4,5 rows. It repeats row5

Comment: I have added an answer please try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ChildNameAccess.java` child is defined outside resultSet iteration, try creating new Child object inside the loop every time it loops. Because in Java strings are immutable, and you actually cannot change the value of a string. Means when you do `child.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));`
like wise original value of the firstName String is still in the memory and the other variables which are pointed to it haven't changed.

```
while(resultSet.next()){
                    Child child = new Child();
                    child.setChildId(resultSet.getString("ChildID"));//database column -->ChildID
                    child.setMotherId(resultSet.getString("MotherID"));
                    child.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
                    child.setLastName(resultSet.getString("LastName"));

                    children.add(child);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't  get what it really happened so far. You're explanation make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create child object for each resultset row. You are not creating it. I have fixed it as follows.

```
 package com.emidwife.web.models.dataAccess;

 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import com.emidwife.web.models.entities.Child;
 import com.emidwife.web.models.utilities.Database;


 public class ChildNameAccess {
 private Database connection = new Database();
  Child child = null;

public List<Child> getChildDataByMotherId(String motherID) throws SQLException {

connection.openConnection();

List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
try{
    ResultSet resultSet = connection.getData("SELECT * FROM childdetails WHERE MotherID=\'" + motherID + "\'");
        while(resultSet.next()){
            child = new Child();
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
        child.setChildId(resultSet.getString("ChildID"));//database column -->ChildID
        child.setMotherId(resultSet.getString("MotherID"));
        child.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
        child.setLastName(resultSet.getString("LastName"));
        System.out.println(children);
        children.add(child);
        System.out.println(children);
    }
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    connection.closeConnection();
}

return children;
}}
```

Comment: Yeah it's working ! But it repeat same name twice.  That means it repeats two different names twice(4 options instead of two)

Comment: That may be because you are not passing a new model object to client view. You update existing model in your controller method.